# What does 「見ちゃいない」mean?

Tags: meaning, colloquial-language, contractions, casual

I came across this in a manga, and I still can't figure out what the ちゃいない means. Does any help please?

Comment: Contraction of 見てはいない?

Comment: Context is always good.  I agree with @user3856370's contraction suggestion, but more context would help us to be more certain in that interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

It's almost certainly a contraction of 見てはいない ("[someone] is not seeing it" or "[someone] has not seen it"). It can also be a contraction of 見てしまいなさい ("Watch it anyway!") at least in one western dialect I know, but it's rare.

In casual speech, ては very often contracts to ちゃ (and では contracts to じゃ). See [Purpose of adj+kucha and noun+ja in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57943/5010) for example.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure that you will sometimes find the expression 見ちゃいない in a manga, because this expression is very colloquial and used in daily conversation. I think the following expressions can arranged in the order of formality. 見てはいない、見ていない、見てない、見ちゃいない。